# Simple autocomplete feature in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, autocomplete

What would be the simplest way to implement autocomplete in lightning component? I need some easy and lightweight solution, i don't want to have several .cls files, and be obligated to write tests afterwards. I have a list of countries in my helper, and i want to use them for my autocomplete select field. Simple as that, any solution?

Comment: I had this specific requirement, and a colleague pointed me to this solution.  You will need to write some controller code, but I think that's unavoidable.  http://michaelsoriano.com/lightning-component-google-places/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the Strike Lookup component found at:

http://lightningStrike.io

Comment: That solution doesn't provide simplicity i am looking for, as i would be required to write tests for apex classes afterwards.

Comment: After a few days of searching, Strike lookup component is definetely the easiest and quickest solution available out of the box. Also i found out that one test class had covered all the apex class files. I will accept this answer, thanks Eric.